# Google Apps Calendar without Email

Tags: google-workspace

Does anyone have experience of using the calendar facilities in Google Apps without using the e-mail part?

We are investigating whether we can use Google Apps for calendaring while keeping our existing e-mail system in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email service in Google Apps is optional, so you could use Calendar without Gmail for Work.

Comment: Just to expand on this a little - you can completely disable mail from the Google Apps control panel